# In what cases can the laravel's eloquent collection save() go wrong?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to know the possible errors or exception that a elqouent's `save()` could throw. In laravel, I have been doing like following when saving or updating a model.

```
    // create or update some data

    if($model->save()){
        // continue
        return true;
    }

    throw new Exception('Model could not be saved');
```

I don't prefer surrounding `save()` with the `if` statement to check if model is saved or not. If it throws an exception then, I would love to wrap it in `try..catch` block like,

```
    try{    
        // create or update some data
        $model->save()
        // continue
        return true;
    catch(SomeException $e){
        throw new Exception('Model could not be saved');
    }
```

So, Can laravel's eloquent collection `save()` go wrong? Or, I am just over thinking about it?

Comment: Examples: database has crashed, network connection to your database has crashed, disk space has filled up on your database server.... there's just a few potential cases listed

Comment: @MarkBaker Yeah you are right. But, these exception are out of our control. Apart from these server error, I want to know about those errors that can be handled from program itself.

Comment: Other possibilities: you're allocating an id manually and it's invalid, or some data value breaks a foreign key constraint on your database

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only exceptions I have encountered is when I have set foreign key constraints and broke them in my code (or by the user), which will throw a QueryException in the form like this:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ...
```

If you want explicit exception throwing, I can think of 2.5 ways:

1. Extend from a base model and override the `save()` method so that if it returns false, it throws its own exception for you to catch.
2. Extend and instead of overriding, name the method `saveOrFail()`.
3. Use this library's `saveOrFail()` method (which does the same as #1) but abstracted away (https://github.com/dwightwatson/validating).

Answer (score 0):

**Can laravel's eloquent collection save() go wrong?**

Yes, behind the scene the save method is calling few model events like creating and saving which returns false if something goes wrong. Read more about [model events](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#model-events)

While if something goes wrong Laravel's App::error will handle exceptions for you.

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{

});
```

Comment: Yeah, I know Laravel handles exception for us. I just want to know if there is more specific exception. I read the link. Thank you for that. So, when `false` is returned from the `creating, updating, saving, or deleting` events, does it throw any exception? If yes what are they?

Comment: No, it doesn't throw exceptions just returns false. In your case you can use QueryException to get the specific error if you are really looking for for errors when saving the model.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 9 i noticed if i don´t provide default values as associative array in the Model, the save() method crashes. The documentation doesnt mention this case, only that i am free to define default values but not what happens if i don´t. Actually i have to. Thats misleading / wrong and causes a lot of trouble and delays in development.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#default-attribute-values